# Rotate a string of integers to match index

Tags: python

> t is number of tests; each test contains two lines: n and sequence
>
> n is number of integers
>
> sequence is a sequence of integers from 1..n (e.g. '3 6 1 2 4 5' if n is 6)
>
> Rotate `sequence` until you maximize the number of integers that match their position in the string. (e.g. '3 6 1 2 4 5' should output '1 2 4 5 3 6'). Print the answer sequence for each test.

Here is the working code. It seems to satisfy the conditions above.

Would be very grateful for any guidance to make it more efficient!

```
def rotate_left(seq):
    return seq[1:] + [seq[0]]

def is_in_position(seq):
    in_position = 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(seq, start=1):
        if int(val) == idx:
            in_position += 1
    return in_position

t = int(raw_input()) #number of tests
while t:
    n = int(raw_input()) #number of integers
    sequence = str(raw_input()).split() #sequence of integers from 1..n

    if not n:
        break

    max_score, answer_sequence = 0, 0

    for i in range(n):
        sequence = rotate_left(sequence)
        sequence_score = is_in_position(sequence)
        if max_score < sequence_score:
            max_score = sequence_score
            answer_sequence = sequence
            answer_sequence = ' '.join(answer_sequence)
        if max_score >= 0.5 * len(sequence):
            break
    if answer_sequence:
        print(answer_sequence)
    t -= 1
```

Comment: The program is supposed to make a best guess and terminate search at some point ? As opposed to running through all possible combinations and returning the best sequence ?

Comment: @peonicles It runs through all possibilities but *all* it does is rotate them. It doesn't do a full re-order, so in many cases it can't put them in 100% correct order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Variable name**

If you were to give `t` a different name, you wouldn't need to comment `number of tests`. I suggest `nb_tests`.

**Looping - the pythonic way**

There are better ways to write :

```
nb_tests = int(raw_input())
while nb_tests:
    ...
    nb_tests -= 1
```

You could use a simple `for` loop.

```
nb_tests = int(raw_input()) 
for _ in range(nb_tests):
```

(I've used `_` as a variable name because this is the convention for unused variables in Python).

**Split the logic into smaller functions**

At the moment, the logic related to input/output is mixed with the logic related to the actual algorithm. It would make things clearer to write proper functions to handle this properly.

```
def get_rotate_sequence_with_best_match(sequence):
    max_score, answer_sequence = 0, []
    n = len(sequence)
    for i in range(n):
        sequence = rotate_left(sequence)
        sequence_score = is_in_position(sequence)
        if max_score < sequence_score:
            max_score = sequence_score
            answer_sequence = sequence
        if max_score >= 0.5 * len(sequence):
            break
    return answer_sequence

nb_tests = int(raw_input())
for _ in range(nb_tests):
    n = int(raw_input())
    sequence = str(raw_input()).split()
    assert len(sequence) == n
    print(' '.join(get_rotate_sequence_with_best_match(sequence)))
```

See also : [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

**`if __name__ == "__main__":`**

It is a good habit to use a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to separate your function definitions to what you actually run when you call your script. It is useful when you want to re-use your code via module import.

**Tests**

Now that you've re-organised a bit your code, it is much easier to write and run unit tests to ensure everything is working properly.

Based on the provided example, I have :

```
def run_test_on_stdin():
    nb_tests = int(raw_input())
    for _ in range(nb_tests):
        n = int(raw_input())
        sequence = str(raw_input()).split()
        assert len(sequence) == n
        print(' '.join(get_rotate_sequence_with_best_match(sequence)))

def run_unit_tests():
    seq = [3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5]
    assert get_rotate_sequence_with_best_match(seq) == [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_unit_tests()
```

**Counting - the pythonic way**

You could use [`sum(iterable[, start])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) in `is_in_position`. Indeed, you could write :

```
def is_in_position(seq):
    return sum(int(val) == idx for idx, val in enumerate(seq, start=1))
```

**Micro-optimisations**

You don't need to always check `if max_score >= 0.5 * len(sequence):` : you just need to check it after updating `max_score`. Also, you could reuse `n` instead of calling `len` every time.

```
def get_rotate_sequence_with_best_match(sequence):
    max_score, answer_sequence = 0, []
    n = len(sequence)
    for i in range(n):
        sequence = rotate_left(sequence)
        sequence_score = is_in_position(sequence)
        if max_score < sequence_score:
            max_score, answer_sequence = sequence_score, sequence
            if max_score >= 0.5 * n:
                break
    return answer_sequence
```

**Different algorithm**

Generating `n` sequences and counting how many of the `n` elements are in the right position gives you an 0(n²) algorithm (at best).

A different strategy could be to look at the shift required for each number to be in the correct position. Because all numbers are in `1...n`, you can compute the shift with a simple substraction and a modulus operation. Doing this for all numbers can be easily done :

```
print([(i - val) % n for i, val in enumerate(sequence, start=1)])
```

Then, you just need to see which elements occurs more often which can be done with [`collection.Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

```
from collections import Counter

def rotate_left(seq, shift=1):
    return seq[shift:] + seq[:shift]


def get_rotate_sequence_with_best_match(sequence):
    n = len(sequence)
    shifts = Counter([(i - val) % n for i, val in enumerate(sequence, start=1)])
    best_shift, nb_occur = shifts.most_common(1)[0]
    return rotate_left(sequence, best_shift)
```